# How to get new URL after submiting form on page that adds random code on URL using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, json, curl

```php
<?php
    $hat2 = 'http://example.com/';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $hat2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

When I click on a button of that page (`example.com`), it adds some more code (e.g. `1425192105017`) to the URL using a JS script.

But I can't get the code on the page itself, like `'http://example.com/xyz?_=1425192105017'`

My question is: how do I get the particular code (`1425192105017`) from `$html`?

I don't know exactly how to get that code from the URL. I didn't use `preg_match` to find that code from the HTML page itself, because it doesn't have that code. A JS script randomly generates the code.

I want that future URL (`http://example.com/xyz?_=code`) from `$html` to use that code in the next curl option.

Comment: It is likely to keep the page out of cache. It will be in location.search on the client. I am not sure if you can get it by name in PHP but it will be in the request array

Comment: when i opened the example.com in browser ..some more pages of JS opens automatically .. in which they have that code itself .... so bro tell that how to get others pages or traffic pages or ad pages ?? and i want to fetch the url(http:// whole line or url) from other pages using php regex??

Comment: Ask them if they have an api. The code could be to keep leaches out